# Jersey 2.7 with Dropwizard 0.7 - is this supported?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, jersey-1.0

I am having a Dropwizard based RESTful application. Dropwizard v0.7 seems to have a dependency on jersey 1.18.

I am trying to upgrade jersey to 2.7 retaining dropwizard 0.7. But there seems to be dependency for dropwizard with jersey 1.18. Being a loosely coupled framework, I was expecting a simple change of maven dependency could solve my problem.

Is this supported or am I trying something that is not officially supported by dropwizard ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support at this time, but there is [an experimental branch by Saad Mufti](https://github.com/saadmufti/dropwizard/tree/jersey-2) that should work. It depends upon modified version of Metrics and I think this is one of the main reasons why it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: This fork has been pulled into Dropwizard and is currently aimed for 0.8.0 - see the pull request (https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/545) and ultimate acceptance (https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/706).

At the time of writing 0.8.0 hadn't been released, but has entered RC status.